# Rounding double precision floats in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to round a double precision float to the nearest int in MIPS.

Here is my code.

```
li $v0, 7
syscall
round.w.d $f2, $f0
```

After I input 10.5, it is then rounded to 10.500000000000018. This round.w.d function is supposed to round the f0 register to the nearest 32 bit int (.word) and then store the result in f2. What am I doing wrong? I cannot find any information indicating that the procedure is incorrect.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
li $v0, 7
syscall
round.w.d $f2, $f0
cvt.d.w $f2, $f2 <--- this fixed the problem.
```